# Get variable OneToOneField in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Lets say I have a `Form` model:

```
class Form(models.Model):
     name = models.TextField()
     date = models.DateField()
```

and various "child" models

```
class FormA(models.Model):
         form = models.OneToOneField(Form, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
         property_a = models.TextField()

class FormB(models.Model):
         form = models.OneToOneField(Form, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
         property_b = models.IntegerField()

class FormC(models.Model):
         form = models.OneToOneField(Form, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
         property_c = models.BooleanField()
```

a `Form` can be one AND ONLY ONE of 3 types of forms (FormA, FormB, FormC). Given a Query Set of `Form`, is there any way I can recover what types of Form (A, B or C) they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need to get a better understanding of your actual use case to know whether this is a good option for you or not, but in these situations, I would first suggest using [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) instead of a one to one field. The code you have there is basically doing what [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) already does.

Take a read through the inheritance docs real quick first and make sure that multi-table inheritance makes sense for you as compared to the other options provided by django. If you do wish to continue with multi-table inheritance, I would suggest taking a look at [InheritanceManager from django-module-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager).

At this point (if using `InheritanceManager`), you would be able to use `isinstance`.

```
for form in Form.objects.select_subclasses():
    if isinstance(form, FormA):
        ..... do stuff ......
```

This might sound like a lot of extra effort but IMO it would reduce the moving parts (and custom code) and make things easier to deal with while still handling the functionality you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it by name or isinstance.

```
a = FormA()
print(a.__class__) 
print(a.__class__.__name__)
print(isinstance(a, Forma))
```

outputs:

```
<class __main__.FormA at 0xsomeaddress>
'FormA'
True
```

------------------- EDIT -----------------
Ok based on your comment, you just want to know which instance is assigned to your main Form.

So you can do something like this:

```
if hasattr(form, 'forma'):
    # do something
elif hasattr(form, 'formb'):
    # do something else
elif hasattr(form, 'formb'):
    # do something else
```

Comment: Apologies, perhaps my question isn't clear enough. Given an instance of Form, I would like to know if that instance is related to FormA, FormB, FormC or none at all.
f = Form()
f.getOneToOne()?

Comment: Thanks, it did help. I was looking for a more dynamic solution (i.e, not previously knowing the type of forms that could be linked to the "father" model in the db) but I was unaware of the hasattr function, this helped me implement the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating a bit I came up with this

```
for form in forms:
    #reduces fields to those of OneToOne types
    one_to_ones = [field for field in form._meta.get_fields() if field.one_to_one] 

    for o in one_to_ones:
        if hasattr(form,o.name):
            #do something
```

Might have some drawbacks (maybe bad runtime) but serves its purpose for now. 
Ideas to improve this are appreciated